Mystery pipe by roadside electrical boxes
There is a wet area in the yard around the electric boxes by the road. I figured I would try to just raise the ground a bit and mulch around them instead of just having soggy grass and found this 4 inch pipe that was buried. It seems to just go to nowhere almost straight down and always filled with water.
Can stick a shovel handle down and it keeps going, no idea how long it is. The water doesn't seem to drain from the back end. Just fills and leaches until it drains or evaporates enough to not be at the top. Any ideas what it could possibly be? Hoping i could just cap it and that would be the end of it.



As mentioned by KMJ, the material looks like ENT flexible electrical conduit. In my region that's not a standard choice for underground use so it surprises me to see it there.
It appears to enter the ground at an angle rather than perpendicularly, and with its location adjacent to other utility pedestals, I think it's unlikely to be a valve access. More likely is that the other end of the conduit or some place along its length is open in a place where there's ground water. The water is flowing by gravity through the pipe and your yard has become the drain. The tube may have been installed at the time the subdivision was built and ultimately has gone unused. Chances are good that it'll never be used.
ENT conduit is sized the same as PVC pipe and is made of PVC. I think it's a reasonable course of action to buy a solvent-weld PVC pipe cap of the correct size and cement it onto the end of this tube.

I don't think ENT is made in sizes that large.  It's either a flexible (corrugated) drain pipe of some sort, which'd be weird, or more likely a flexible HDPE conduit

@ThreePhaseEel With nothing but blades of grass for scale it's tough, but this looks like 3-4" to me. I was dubious of ENT that large too. Carlon only goes up to 2", but to my shock and surprise, I just discovered Cantex actually does list 2-1/2, 3, and 4 on their web site.

Yeah, I think you're right that it exists in sizes that large, but is rare -- HDPE would be more probable given the size and context

Description sounds like a valve access riser for a water or sewer line valve buried below frost line. Could also be gas, I suppose. Should have a cover identifying the service, but sometimes those go missing. A long pipe with a claw-looking thing on the end is used to turn the valve.
Picture looks more like empty conduit for future use by some utility, though.

Looks like ENT, so I think your second theory is more likely. No idea why it would fill with water though. I think that might be a red herring.

All exterior conduits are defined as wet. Most meet the definition. Condensate alone will do it if there are no leaks. Surface water can clearly add to that in this case.

Sure, but a buried pipe doesn't automatically bring more water in to an area, which is part of what the asker was posing.
